# Window shortcuts in Chrome suddenly changed

Tags: google-chrome

I haven't updated or made any recent changes to Chrome. I'm wondering why my Chrome suddenly changed from

[image: this]

to

[image: this]

Comment: So the menu bar is missing?

Comment: That's the bookmark bar. Press Ctrl+Shift+B.

Comment: I'm referring to the minimize, fullscreen, and close button.